# How to tell whether I need to keep a version of .net framework?

Tags: .net-framework

Overtime I accumulated a bunch of .net versions.
I'm rather certain some of them are not used anymore by any installed application.
How do I check that? In other words, is there a (simple) tool, which perhaps is part of .net itself, that can scan my .net installation directory and tell me which versions are obsolete/unused?

thank you.

Comment: Uninstall all and install the latest?

Comment: Why? (out of curiosity)

Comment: This requires a pragmatic approach.  You can tell by uninstalling it.  If that doesn't make an app you use crash and burn then you didn't need it.  You fix it by putting it back.

Comment: Your first reply has been removed by a moderator. This is not a discussion forum, so answers to a question should be just that: *answers*. To associate the question with your account to be able to edit it or comment on answers, register on this site with the same Open ID/Account as on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you won't find such a tool, but others may prove me wrong. I do think it helps if you realize that there are actually 2 major version into use right now, and that it's safest to keep them both: .NET 2 Framework and .NET 4 Framework.

There are still a lot of applications using the older 2 version that do not necessarily run wel on 4. So while you may uninstall it, you might find yourself reinstalling it again when you encounter such an application.

On top of that, I think it's also pretty safe to assume that 1 is largely deprecated and very likely to be unused. Only if you have legacy software from 10 years back, you'll need this one.

Furthermore: 3.0 and 3.5 are just enhancements on 2.0. So as long as you keep 2.0, there's no point in getting rid of these. Otoh, if you loose 2.0, you'll loose these too.

And to conclude: I have no experience with 4.5, but from what I read, it's an in-replace update of 4.0. So either you have 4.0 or you have 4.5.

Comment: Just to clarify what Grimace was saying to cover all .NET apps all you need installed is the most recent version of 3.5 (currently [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22)) and you need the most recent version of the 4.x line your computer can support, 4.5 is not supported on XP ([it requires Vista or newer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx)) so the newest version you can get at the time of this writing is [4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851).